# Matlab od45 question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I am learning to use Matlab's `ode45` to solve this equation and plot its time history:

$$I_gd\omega/dt + \omega \times (I_g\omega) = 0$$

It was suggested that I use:

`omega_dot = fun(t,omega)` ...

```
global I_G
I_G = I_g(:,:,m);
a = I_G*omega;
b = cross(omega,a);
omega_dot = -I_G/b;
```

`I_g` is a 3-by-3 inertia matrix predefined in another piece of code. My time vector is `tspan = [0 100]`. The initial state vector is `omega = [1 0 0]`.

I understand that I need to set up my code in the form:

```
[t,y] = ode45(@vdpl,[0 20],[2 0]);
plot (t,y(:,1));
```

I need suggestions on how to make the information that I have work with the information that the examples for `ode45` suggest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. First, *don't use global variables*. [There's no need.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) And [they're inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888899/global-could-be-very-inefficient). The code below shows how to pass in parameters such as your `I_G` matrix (note that `integrationfun` now has a third input argument). Second, you didn't define `m` – it can be passed in just like `I_G` if it's constant (though then it'd make more sense to just pass in `I_g(:,:,m)`) or you can define it in your integration function. You can define one main function with a sub-function that describes the ODE:

```
function mainfun
tspan = [0 100];
omega0 = [1 0 0].';
I_G = ... % Define here, passed into integrationfun
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y)integrationfun(t,y,I_G),tspan,omega0);
plot (t,y(:,1));

function omega_dot = integrationfun(t,omega,I_G)
m = ... % Define m
I_G = I_g(:,:,m);
a = I_G*omega;
b = cross(omega,a);
omega_dot = -I_G/b;
```

By the way, I'm not sure the last line of your integration function matches up with the differential equation you specified.

Comment: ~ thank you so much for your input.  Sorry it took so long to respond.  Just some notes for more input.....m = 1:1000 right now, although it will most likely become 1:10,000.  I_G was made global because it will be used in another piece of code.  I_g(:,:,m) is an inertial matrix that is randomly generated in that other piece of code. Does it need to be called in?  Again, thank you for your time.  It is much appreciated!  :)

Comment: Yes, there seems to be no reason to use globals. You can either define `I_G` directly in your equivalent of `mainfun` or you can use a function that `mainfun` calls to define `I_G` and return it as an output. You'll still have to set `m`. Is the idea to simulate 1,000 systems with different random inertia matrices and plot each?

Comment: ~ Ig(:,:,m)=Igbar-MY'*Y*I3 + M*Y*Y'.  The components M,Y and Igbar are parts of a randomly generated matrix, Mr.  (All of which are saved in another piece of code).  So to answer your last question yes.  Ultimately I'll compare the response of those systems to a mean model system where c=g.  "Nonparametric stochastic modeling of structural uncertainty".  I have no background in Matlab though.  So I'm learning as I go.  :)